# How to express "lucky" in formal writing?

Tags: expressions, formality, redundancy

> I feel very lucky that I chose CS, and feel even luckier that I went into this field midway in my journey. As an outsider, I am not constrained by rules.

Are these sentences authentic English? I feel they are redundant but cannot improve it. Below is the context.

> After failing to build a bionic robot, I designed a soft artificial muscle which can shrink when electrified. I believe it may have potential use in robotics. Some projects like dynamic levitation model of solar system and Flying Hammer will be put on Kickstarter in June. **I feel very lucky that I chose CS, and feel even luckier that I went into this field midway in my journey. As an outsider, I am not constrained by rules.** On the contrary, my interdisciplinary perspective and aspiration always motivate me to try something which is traditionally regarded as impossible. With technology in my hands, changing the world is no longer mere enthusiasm.

Comment: "I was very fortunate to have chosen..." You may also try, "It turned out to be a good decision to choose..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would use **fortunate** instead of **lucky.** I think the former is *more formal and better suited* to your needs.

You could also rework the sentence so as to *avoid the double use of the word* in question. For example:

> I consider myself very **fortunate** to have chosen CS, especially at this
>   opportune midway point in my career. Happily, I am an outsider in the
>   world of CS, unconstrained by the rules with which others are so familiar.

Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but to me, it fits more naturally within the paragraph you've posted.

Comment: Oh my god. I worked on this for several days but couldn't figure out a way to improve it. Your answer immediately brings my writing to another level. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're certainly welcome. Good luck!

Comment: I type the word, this time lucky and add the word synonym into my Google search engine. [lucky synonym and it brings up a main definition and links to sites with synonyms for my word.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=lucky+synonym)